# does [NSFont systemFontOfSize] memory needs to be released

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to lower the footprint of memory my application uses at runtime....

In the standard usage to get a font based on system font size the api is used as `font = [NSFont systemFontOfSize]`

```
+ (NSFont *)systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize; // Aqua System font
```

As per my understanding that the `font` will be freed by the autorelease pool, First I need to confirm that this understating is correct?

If this is correct, then if I have a `drawWithFrame` function where I am using this every time I draw a cell. Should I not release it there? and would increasing the memory footprint of the application, since the fonts would be freed when the applications autorelease pool is called?

Now is again this understanding is correct? There are 2 approaches

- Find a way to release NSFont
- Put a `NSAutoReleasePool *pool`. alloc / release there itself in draw with frame

What do you guys suggest?

Comment: If you're worried about your memory footprint, use Instruments's Allocations instrument to find out both how much memory you're using and what you're using it on. It's probably not NSFont objects; more to the point, if it is, you'll gain hard evidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not use to dealing with `Font` so I might be out of the way.

But to me if you frequently need and object, I would cache it in a property.
Creating and deletion is more expensive than reading a property.

And if this is a key feature of your class, I would event create it in the `init` of my class.
That would save the unnecessary test to see if it already exist.

Comment: this can be a partial solution, but how to trim the piled up objects which would be lazily autorelease

Comment: if you don't create them every time they won't pile up because you will always have only one.

Answer (score 2):

The function name `systemFontOfSize:` doesn't begin with any of the magic keywords "alloc", "new", "copy", or "mutableCopy", so you aren't responsible for releasing what it returns. See the [Cocoa basic memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) for details.

Comment: But it would still pile up in memory, increasing footprint :(

Comment: No, actually it won't. It's quite likely that `systemFontOfSize:` is returning you an object that the system was already using internally. If it isn't, the object will be autoreleased.

Answer (score 0):

As with most non-"init" methods that return an object ("copy" is an exception that pops to mind) the object returned by systemFontOfSize is autoreleased and so it will be released at some point in the (very near) future.

If you want to use the object pointed to by your variable "font" outside of the local scope you should retain it and release it when it's no longer needed (or before being replaced by another font)

Edit: I just reread realized you're creating the font every time so the 2nd paragraph isn't so relevant to your question, but anyway, unless the font is something that has to change many times a second I'd consider creating the font object outside the drawrect method. I don't know how much of a practical effect this specifically would have on your current FPS/responsiveness but it's generally good to get used to not doing stuff such as object creation redundantly multiple times in loops etc.

Comment: interesting, how to figure out very near future, is it the scope?

Comment: `autorelease` is call at the end of the run loop, it's a very near future if you're not doing infinite loops.

Comment: @user970251 well it seems to be some sort of a consensus to use "sometime in the future" to answer "when does the framework's autorelease pool drain", the definition is probably vague because you shouldn't make any assumptions about when it's actually going to happen. Technically, to pool drains at the end of the run loop cycle, but you shouldn't try to predict and work according to that prediction because that's implementation details. If you want precise control over when the uifont deallocates you should do what chown proposed in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct on both items.  By convention, all named initializers return autoreleased objects.  Since you (scope of `drawWithFrame`) did not excplicitly allocate `font` you are not responsible for releasing it.  Like you also suggested, this can be optimizated by putting an `autorelease` pool around it.
<sub>Wether or not the benefit is worth the extra typing work of the coder is debatable.</sub>

Comment: @user970251 np, happy to help.